# React+Redux: Dispatching action from inside const that is outside of class declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component, EditableTable, that I'm binding keyboard responses to. When they get to the end of the row or column, I want to create another row/column if the user presses the right or down key. The problem I'm having is that I am not able to dispatch my actions from inside the functions I created outside of the class declaration.

`EditableTable.js`

```
const bindKeyboard = (event) => {
switch(event.key) {
  case 'ArrowUp': onUpPress(event);
  break;
  case 'ArrowDown': onDownPress(event);
  break; 
  case 'ArrowLeft': onLeftPress(event);
  break;
  case 'ArrowRight': onRightPress(event);
  break;
  default: console.log("key pressed "+event.key);
  }
 }

const onDownPress = (event) => {
let cell = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
let id = cell.id.split(' ');
let nextRowCell = id[0]*1+1;
let column = cell.dataset.column;


if(event.target.name == "tableHeader" && cell != null) {
    document.getElementById(1+" "+column).focus();
} else if(document.getElementById(nextRowCell) == null) {

    //want to dispatch action here
    (event) => this.props.handleAddRow(event.target.id);

} else {
    document.getElementById(nextRowCell+" "+column).focus();
    }
 }

...Some code

class EditableTable extends React.Component {

...

return <input name="tableHeader" data-row={0} data-column={index} id={index} defaultValue={title} 
                        key={index}
                        onChange={(event) => this.props.handleHeaderChange(event.target.id, event.target.value)} 
                        onKeyDown={(event) => this.props.bindKeyboard(event)}
                        style={tableStyles.header} />
```

Comment: Why not call this in `mapDispatchToProps` where you have access to dispatch?

Comment: Well I'm trying to get this to call mapDispatchToProps, but in onKeyDown in input I have to call bindKeyboard because there are multiple key down options. Also, I tried to put the bindKeyboard and onDownPress functions into my container that has mapDispatchToProps but then the keys to move from one cell of the table to another no longer work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you move your event handlers inside the component class?

You can also get a reference to the store (but that depends on the rest of your code), and then call `store.dispatch(yourAction);`

Comment: I moved my event handlers into my constructor then called my action and now it works! Thank you so much!